# How to get second td value from a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

Tried to get table's tr second td value but not working.I think closest is not working in chrome or firefox properly. I am using this script in angular 6.How to resolve this issue?

```
const target = e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('td');
```

Comment: please write html file too

Comment: @miladfm: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6maxqx?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Did you try any debugging at all? Are you sure `target` is is grabbing a `tr` element correctly?

Comment: @StephenMIrving: e.originalEvent.toElement is working fine but closest is not working

Comment: @NilaVaani, What is the output of  ```e.originalEvent.toElement```?

Comment: `closest` has decent browser compatibility: https://caniuse.com/#search=closest. What `console.log(e.originalEvent.toElement)` would print? then what `console.log(e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr')` prints

Comment: Btw why would you want to directly manipulate the DOM while using Angular: https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/6btma7/whats_so_wrong_with_direct_dom_manipulation/

Comment: e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('div') is working fine but if i use tr or td is not working

Comment: @NilaVaani, Can you try my below given solution? That gives you how to fetch the data you wish from table ```tr``` and ```td```..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan:you did not use any event

Comment: @NilaVaani, THe solution is pure javascript form.. In stackblitz I could not able to get the line ```e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('div')``` executable.. Can you eloborate what should i need to do to view the console in ```onSelectType(e)``` I have tried inputting some text in select box but it doesn't run..

Comment: Can you produce the code that `e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('div')` works meanwhile `e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr')` doesn't work please.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh: Yes..e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('tr') is not working

Comment: @NilaVaani meanwhile `e.originalEvent.toElement.closest('div')` is working? Can you produce the code demonstrates that.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the title of your question and looking at the option "Get ID" from your drop-down, I assume that you simply want to know how to write the ID of the current table row to `component.selectedVal`.

Since you're building individual table rows by iterating over the `component.data` array, the solution is straight forward. Just add below event handler to your `p-dropdown` element and get rid of the method `component.onSelectType`.

```
(onChange)="selectedVal= data"
```

Please have look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7cvqkz?file=src/app/app.component.html)